# custom or subclass the group box control in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, custom-controls

How to make group box/ static control to do subclass or custom control.

How to get all the Group box / static controls count. So that i can apply the rounded corners to all Group Box/ static controls.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make group box/ static control to do subclass or custom
>   control.

Derive a class from `CButton`. Handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761847(v=vs.85).aspx) notification to do the custom drawing. Alternatively one could use `BS_OWNERDRAW` window style, but this is mutually exclusive with `BS_GROUPBOX`. When using `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` the original window style flags can be kept.

Note that `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` is normally sent to the parent window, but you can reroute this message to handle it in the control class like this:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyGroupBox, CButton)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, OnCustomDraw)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The definition of `OnCustomDraw()` would look like this:

```
void CMyGroupBox::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    auto pnmc = reinterpret_cast<NMCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR );
    // Query pnmc members and do the custom drawing as documented on MSDN.
    // Assign the result to *pResult.
}
```

> How to get all the Group box / static controls count.

Use [`EnumChildWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all child windows. In the callback call `GetClassName()` to check if the windows class is "button" and call `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)` to check if the `BS_GROUPBOX` flag is set.